# Unity 3D enter Number in Inputfield and get an event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input-field

In my game is a Gamobject. If I interact with it by pressing E the inputfield and the Submit button show up.

How can I enter something into the inputField? I figured out to get the mouse by pressing ESC but that aint a beautiful way to do it.

I have seen ways to save the value of inputFields as Strings. does it work the same way with integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you declared inputfield in your script:

```
public InputField inputField1;
```

Try to activate inputfield after showing it:

```
inputField1.ActivateInputField();
```

To save the value of inputField as integer you need to convert its value to int:

```
var value = int.Parse(inputField1.text);
```

Comment: I made it appear once i interacted with the object. if i  activate it, does it give me the cursor ingame to enter the field?

Comment: You should probably rather use `Int.TryParse(string, out int);` instead since `int.Parse` throws an exception if given string is not a numerical. `TryParse` uses the default value `0` instead .. depends on your needs. You should at least use `Parse` only within a `try - catch` block